# How to convert the DataInputStream to the String in Java?

Tags: java, string

I want to ask a question about Java. I have use the URLConnection in Java to retrieve the DataInputStream. and I want to convert the DataInputStream into a String variable in Java. What should I do? Can anyone help me. thank you.

The following is my code:

```
URL data = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection dataConnection = data.openConnection();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(dataConnection.getInputStream());
String data_string;
// convent the DataInputStream to the String
```

Comment: you want to convert DataInputString to String or you want to read String from DataInputString?

Comment: @org.life.java, thank you for your reply. I want to convent the DataInputStream to string, like (data_string = dis;). by the way, I think it is another question, so I post a new question, no the old question I ask. Thank you. :-)

Comment: to convert you can just say `String str = dis.toString();` , but It will give you string representation of Object, I don't understand why you need this ? Or you want to read the content of google.com here ?

Comment: @org.life.java, thank you for your reply. The google is just a example and I want to ask, what do you mean by 'give you string representation of Object'?

Comment: Object has a method toString that Returns a string representation of the object.I don;t think you are looking for that , What you want to do exactly by converting dis to String , explain with example .

Comment: @org.life.java, thank you for your reply. my aim is to get the HTML content to be a string. like, String a = "<html><head> ....". Thank you.

Comment: @org.life.java, thank you. Also reply your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ConnectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            URLConnection googleConnection = google.openConnection();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(googleConnection.getInputStream());
            StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
            String tmp; 
            while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                inputLine.append(tmp);
                System.out.println(tmp);
            }
            //use inputLine.toString(); here it would have whole source
            dis.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + me);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what you want.

Comment: @org.life.java, thank you for your answer. And i think there is some misunderstand of the problem. After the 'System.out.println(inputLine);', the inputLine become 'null' value and I want the inputLine="<html><head..." and use in other class future. So, would you mind to give me another suggestion? thank you.

Comment: @org.life.java, a great great great help. thank you very much and sorry to lose your time.

Comment: I don't believe this can work. `readUTF()` expects string data to be stored in a specific way (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29). This will not be the case if you try to read content from an arbitrary URL.

Comment: @Grodriguez  Thanks foe letting me know that. I have altered it back to readLine, I know its depricated .other solution are already here like bozho's

Comment: If you use `DataInputStream.readLine()`, your solution will not work correctly if the content encoding of the URL you are accessing is anything different than plain ASCII. This is why the `readLine` method is deprecated. See my answer to this same question for a way to read the contents of the URL taking into account the content encoding, without resorting to any external libraries.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) `IOUtils.toString(dataConnection.getInputStream(), encoding)` in order to achieve your goal.

`DataInputStream` is not used for what you want - i.e. you want to read the content of a website as `String`.

Comment: This does not take into account the content encoding for the URL you are accessing. You should use the two argument version of the `IOUtils.toString` method in order to explicitly specify the encoding.

Comment: @Grodriguez or use an `InputStreamReader`. I added the encoding, a good practice indeed.

Comment: Even if you pass an `InputStreamReader` instead, you still need to specify the encoding when the `InputStreamReader` is created, otherwise you will have the same problem (the default platform encoding would be used, which may or may not match the encoding of the URL content).

Comment: @Grodriguez that's what I meant by the `InputStreamReader` suggestion. (Btw the downvote can be removed, I guess)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to read data from a generic URL (such as `www.google.com`), you probably don't want to use a `DataInputStream` at all. Instead, create a `BufferedReader` and read line by line with the `readLine()` method. Use the `URLConnection.getContentType()` field to find out the content's charset (you will need this in order to create your reader properly).

Example:

```
URL data = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection dataConnection = data.openConnection();

// Find out charset, default to ISO-8859-1 if unknown
String charset = "ISO-8859-1";
String contentType = dataConnection.getContentType();
if (contentType != null) {
    int pos = contentType.indexOf("charset=");
    if (pos != -1) {
        charset = contentType.substring(pos + "charset=".length());
    }
}

// Create reader and read string data
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(dataConnection.getInputStream(), charset));
String content = "";
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    content += line + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Does the ContentEncoding header really contain character set? According to [specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) it should contain eg. gzip. You should be looking at charset.