# Read text and binary from one stream in Java

Tags: java, string, file, http

I'd like to read text and binary from a stream, where the stream could be a file or a URL connection.  Both streams have the same format, where there's an ASCII text header followed by a large binary block of data.  I'm using DataInputStream to do this.  For files, I'm using

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("test")));
```

For URL's, I'm using (where uc is initialized to point to a URL):

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream()));
```

After setting up the DataInputStream, I follow that with:

```
dis.readLine()
dis.read(buf);
```

This works, but I noticed that readLine is [depecrated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) (even though there are [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870847/how-to-convert-the-datainputstream-to-the-string-in-java) that refer to using it).  Is it OK to keep using it since my text is ASCII?  If that's not a good idea, and I go with the JDK recommendation to use BufferedReader, is there a way to access both text and binary?  I tried BufferedReader to get the text header, but then I got incorrect binary data when using the underlying stream, probably because some of it was already consumed.

Comment: How long are the ASCII text headers?  Are they of fixed length?  Could you read the header as "binary data" and convert to one or more Strings?

Comment: The header is variable length, and I need to look for a delimiter to know where the binary data starts.  But as you say, I think I can read the text as binary (using readByte) and build up a String.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was deprecated was the failure to properly convert bytes to chars.  Since this example is limited to ASCII, there's no problem in using it.