# How can i read string data from server ? (swift client - android server)

Tags: android, sockets, server, client

This is swift code (client side):

```
    let text: String = "neslihan"

    var data = NSData(data: text.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)

    outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
```

This is the android code (server side)

```
  public class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public int socketServerPORT = 3671;
    Socket socket = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(socketServerPORT));

            while (true) {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                Log.d("messageFromClient = " , dataInputStream.readUTF());
           }
      }
 }
```

There is connection but i can't see log. How can i read string data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the DataInputStream to the String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870847/how-to-convert-the-datainputstream-to-the-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
while(true){
   socket = serverSocket.accept();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

   Log.d("messageFromClient = " , br.readLine());
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flush to commit write data

`outputStream.flush()`